# Is there a way to parse include paths from CMakeFiles.txt?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, dependencies

I am working on a project where we need to find the internal dependencies of a C/C++ project. To do so, I need to find the include paths for each source directory of the project.

If the project is built with a Makefile then I can use `make -n` to know exactly which `-I` options are used for what file.

If the project is instead built with a CMakeLists.txt file then I have no idea on how to proceed.
[CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html#:%7E:text=Add%20include%20directories%20to%20the%20build.&text=Add%20the%20given%20directories%20to,for%20the%20current%20CMakeLists%20file.) uses

```
include_directories([AFTER|BEFORE] [SYSTEM] dir1 [dir2 ...])  # OR....

target_include_directories(<target> [SYSTEM] [BEFORE]
  <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items1...]
  [<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items2...] ...]))
```

to denote what include directories to use, but excluding the trivial case where the directory is specified directly, I have no idea how to find the include paths.

So my question is, does anyone know how to extract the include paths used for each folder/file from a CMakeLists.txt?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to parse the CMakeLists.txt to get that information, but can use the compiler flags of the `-M<x>` family to obtain a list of the header dependencies of each source file. Here's a solution which does this using `make`: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: Also to know what's used by CMake, you can just output the contents of the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` variable using the `MESSAGE()` command..

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html

Comment: You could also run "include what you use" to minimize the dependencies.